# JSF Compound EL expression

Tags: jsf, el

I am trying to validate a inputText box based on the selection of a CheckBox as shown below. 
 `< <h:inputText required="#{param[facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace'form:checkBoxId']}">  >`.

The issue is as you see, the component Ids are dynamic, I should be able to use facesContext.externalContext.response.namespace inside the EL expression. Is there a solution to it, appreciate any suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bind the `UIComponent` to a page scoped property and access its `getValue()` method.

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{checkbox}" />
<h:inputText required="#{not empty checkbox.value and checkbox.value}" />
```

As to the dynamicness, you can also go around by just giving it a fixed id.

```
<h:form id="form">
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkbox" />
    <h:inputText required="#{not empty param['form:checkbox'] and param['form:checkbox']}" />
</h:form>
```

It's however only ugly when it gets lengthy.